# How remove mask texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-painting, masking

I was painting a texture on an object, and then i click on 'Mask' tool. But i have an error:

[image]

My question is simple: how i retrieve my paint tools? I don't want to use a mask.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish that, but try going to Slots tab and unchecking Mask scroll if it's checked, then click on desired paint slot to activate it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brush you have selected has it's type set to mask and there is no image chosen as the stencil image. Most likely you selected the mask brush.

To get out of it, you need to select a stencil image, then you can change the brush or the brush type. You then need to remove the stencil image from the slots menu or by disabling the "Mask" checkbox.